# Row-wise operation in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a World Indicator dataset that has this format

```
country     year    indicatorName       value
USA         1970    Agricultural Land   ...
USA         1970    Crop production     ...
...
USA         2000    Agricultural Land   ...
USA         2000    Crop production     ...
...
Mexico      1970    Agricultural Land   ...
Mexico      1970    Crop production     ...
...
Mexico      2000    Agricultural Land   ...
Mexico      2000    Crop production     ...
```

There are indicators here that I did not include, but these two are what I'm interested in. I want to divide the corresponding `value` of `Crop production` to `Agricultural Land` per `country` per `year`.  Let's name the result `crop_prod_density`.

I do not know how to proceed from

```
df.groupby(['country', 'year'])
```

How to do it from here to result the following outputs:

1. Add new row indicator

`country        year    indicatorName       value
 USA            1970    Agricultural Land   ...
 USA            1970    Crop production     ...
 USA            1970    crop_prod_density   ...`

2. Add new column with same values for all rows for grouped (country, year)

`country    year    indicatorName       value   crop_prod_density
 USA        1970    Agricultural Land   ...     us_value_1970
 USA        1970    Crop production     ...     us_value_1970
 ...
 Mexico     2000    Agricultural Land   ...     mx_value_2000
 Mexico     2000    Crop production     ...     mx_value_2000`

3. New dataframe with only this column for values

`country        year    crop_prod_density
 USA            1970    us_value_1970
 ...
 USA            2000    us_value_2000
 ...
 Mexico         1970    mx_value_1970
 ...
 Mexico         2000    mx_value_2000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and then divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
print (df)
  country  year      indicatorName  value
0     USA  1970  Agricultural Land     10
1     USA  1970    Crop production      2
2     USA  2000  Agricultural Land     10
3     USA  2000    Crop production      3
4  Mexico  1970  Agricultural Land     10
5  Mexico  1970    Crop production      5
6  Mexico  2000  Agricultural Land     10
7  Mexico  2000    Crop production      4  

df = (df.set_index(['country','year','indicatorName'])['value']
       .unstack()
       .assign(crop_prod_density=lambda x: x['Crop production'].div(x['Agricultural Land'])))
print (df)
indicatorName  Agricultural Land  Crop production  crop_prod_density
country year                                                        
Mexico  1970                  10                5                0.5
        2000                  10                4                0.4
USA     1970                  10                2                0.2
        2000                  10                3                0.3
```

Then reshape back by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(name='value')
print (df1)
   country  year      indicatorName  value
0   Mexico  1970  Agricultural Land   10.0
1   Mexico  1970    Crop production    5.0
2   Mexico  1970  crop_prod_density    0.5
3   Mexico  2000  Agricultural Land   10.0
4   Mexico  2000    Crop production    4.0
5   Mexico  2000  crop_prod_density    0.4
6      USA  1970  Agricultural Land   10.0
7      USA  1970    Crop production    2.0
8      USA  1970  crop_prod_density    0.2
9      USA  2000  Agricultural Land   10.0
10     USA  2000    Crop production    3.0
11     USA  2000  crop_prod_density    0.3
```

For new column to original append to index new column, but last is necessary change order of columns by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2 =(df.set_index(['crop_prod_density'], append=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='value')
        .reindex(columns=['country','year','indicatorName','value','crop_prod_density']))
print (df2)
  country  year      indicatorName  value  crop_prod_density
0  Mexico  1970  Agricultural Land     10                0.5
1  Mexico  1970    Crop production      5                0.5
2  Mexico  2000  Agricultural Land     10                0.4
3  Mexico  2000    Crop production      4                0.4
4     USA  1970  Agricultural Land     10                0.2
5     USA  1970    Crop production      2                0.2
6     USA  2000  Agricultural Land     10                0.3
7     USA  2000    Crop production      3                0.3
```

And last remove unnecessary columns and create columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
df3 = (df.drop(['Crop production','Agricultural Land'], axis=1)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, 1))
print (df3)
  country  year  crop_prod_density
0  Mexico  1970                0.5
1  Mexico  2000                0.4
2     USA  1970                0.2
3     USA  2000                0.3
```